# How to upload a ftl file, render the content, and read the attributes of a ftl file inside a react project?

Tags: reactjs, freemarker

**Background**

I am entirely new to free marker template files. I have searched on integrating react applications with ftl. But, haven't found any resources regarding this. I wonder whether this is achievable or not.

**The things I want to achieve are;**

- Upload an ftl file in a way that I can render the file's content inside the react app.
- Render the template inside a react app.
- Identify the attributes/variables defined in the ftl file.

**Additional Info:**

- In my requirement, the ftl file contains an email template.

Please let me know if more information is needed. An answer which explains why it is not achievable is also welcomed. It would minimize fellow developers' time spent searching on this topic.

Comment: "Extract the attributes/variables defined in the ftl file"? The way it works is the opposite. You specify the variables for the template, you run the template, it generates the output. The output is just a flat sequence of characters. You can't get variables from a template.

Comment: @ddekany Sorry for the confusion. I need to identify what are the variables (variable names). The next step would be setting values to those variables. The requirement asks me to do all of these in the react app. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: It's generally not possible to figure out what variables a template will read. It's possible to guess by walking the AST starting out from `Template.getRootTreeNode()`, but it's ugly, and you rely on non-public API.

Comment: Also, just in case it wasn't clear, React is client side, and FreeMarker is server side. Because of that, if the clients can specify arbitrary templates, you have to be extra careful, as basically they write little programs that will run on your server. (See related FAQ on official homepage.)